# How to group PHP arrays by key before sorting by another key?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have an array that contains the key `counted` and `placement` which I am trying to group by before I sort. The array should be first sorted by `counted` and then, for each duplicate `counted`, should then sort by `placement`.

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'placement' => 8,
        'counted' => 3
        'user' => ['name' => 'foo'],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'placement' => 5,
        'counted' => 3
        'user' => ['name' => 'bar'],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'placement' => 1,
        'counted' => 2
        'user' => ['name' => 'foobar'],
    ]
];
```

My expected output here would be:

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'placement' => 5,
        'counted' => 3
        'user' => ['name' => 'bar'],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'placement' => 8,
        'counted' => 3
        'user' => ['name' => 'foo'],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'placement' => 1,
        'counted' => 2
        'user' => ['name' => 'foobar'],
    ]
];
```

I have tried to `usort` to achieve this:

```
usort($array, fn($a, $b) => ((int)$a['placement'] <=> (int)$b['counted']) * -1);
```

But this gives me an unexpected result. Everything I try seems to not work, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to group by placement and counted then sort by counted then sort again by placement? like that? you mean?

Comment: That makes more sense, I think that is what I need to do yeah. The idea is, the array should first be sorted by the `counted`. If multiple users have the same number of `counted`, they should be scored then based on their `placement` @Jerson

Comment: sort by `counted` desc and then sort by `placement` asc ?

Comment: The `placement` shouldn't effect the entire array though, I feel like this needs to be a loop job. My expected output shows what I need, although `id` 3 has the highest `placement`, it has the lowest `counted` and `counted` takes precedence in the sort @rubys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you prefer using usort so this is my answser

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'placement' => 8,
        'counted' => 3,
        'user' => ['name' => 'foo'],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'placement' => 5,
        'counted' => 3,
        'user' => ['name' => 'bar'],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'placement' => 1,
        'counted' => 2,
        'user' => ['name' => 'foobar'],
    ]
];


usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['counted'] < $b['counted']) {
        return 1;
    }

    if ($a['counted'] === $b['counted'] && $a['placement'] > $b['placement']) {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I couldn't think how actually to use `usort` correctly  to match this query. Thankyou!

Comment: @Jaquarh, I also had some trouble working with usort before, hope this will give u more learning :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t care about efficiency, you can write like this

```
collect($array)
    ->sortByDesc('counted')
    ->groupBy('counted')
    ->map(function ($group) {
        return $group->sortBy('placement');
    })
    ->flatten(1)
    ->toArray()
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but it doesn't give the expected output

Comment: I forgot to call `flatten(1)`